# To print elements using nested tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, nested-table

I am working on a procedure which has two parameters with collection type.
Sample data:

**`accounts`**

```
accountid     
2                
3                  
4
```

**`rts_accounts`**

```
accountid
2  
3  
5
```

**input:** 1,2,3,4,5
**desired output:** 4,5

I know we can achieve it by normal sql but I want it in with a collection because our table has millions of records. Please someone help me to solve this issue using collection method.

My code so far:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE delete_account_stg (  
       in_accounts IN  test_coll,  
       out_accounts       OUT test_coll)  
IS  
 result_coll test_coll;  
 result1_coll test_coll;  
BEGIN  
  SELECT test_type( account_id )  
  BULK COLLECT INTO result_coll  
  FROM table(in_accounts);  

 select  test_type(a.account_id )  
 bulk collect into result1_coll  
 from accounts a inner join rts_accounts b on a.account_id = b.account_id;  

select result_coll MULTISET except  result1_coll into out_accounts from dual;  

END delete_account_stg;
```

I am getting output as:
`1,4,5` but I want `4,5`.

Comment: @AlexPoole joing of table will give 2 & 3 not 2,3,4. Because of performance i am using collections.

Comment: Right, I misread that somehow. OK, so it will give `1,4,5`. You still haven't said *why* it should not include `1` in that collection though?

Comment: @AlexPoole that is the specification

Comment: The specification is that `1` should never appear in any result? Seems unlikely. So what is the logic for excluding `1` from *this* result? (I can hazard a guess that it might be because it doesn't appear in either of the original tables, maybe?)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes becaues 1 is not present in either of the tables